# Why is my Bootstrap Carousel not moving from the second slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 2.1.1 for a site. When adding a slideshow using the Bootstrap Carousel plugin, the slideshow ends after reaching the final slide, instead of looping. This was apparently a bug in Bootstrap 2.x that was resolved in Bootstrap 3.

A full-site upgrade to Bootstrap 3 is not currently feasible, so I updated just the Carousel plugin.

However, this has lead to an issue where the first slide transitions to the second, but then the slideshow stops.

This JavaScript error occurs:

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function js_plugins:482 (equivalent 147)

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide loading-indicator" style="margin-top: -40px; margin-bottom: 0; {if segment_1 != ""}z-index: -10;{/if}">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            {exp:low_reorder:entries set="homepage_keywords" channel="home"}
                <div class="item{if count == 1} active{/if}">
                    <img src="{background_image}" alt="{keyword}" title="{keyword}" />
                </div>
            {/exp:low_reorder:entries}
            {if segment_1 == ""}
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <a href="{site_url}media/latest_news" style="colour: white !important; text-decoration: none !important;">
                        <p>
                            <strong>Latest News: </strong>
                            {exp:channel:entries channel="latest_news" limit="1" orderby="date" sort="desc"}
                                {title} &rarr;
                            {/exp:channel:entries}
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            {/if}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Bootstrap 3 Carousel plugin JavaScript has not been modified and is as follows:

```
/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: carousel.js v3.2.0
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */


+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // CAROUSEL CLASS DEFINITION
  // =========================

  var Carousel = function (element, options) {
    this.$element    = $(element).on('keydown.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.keydown, this))
    this.$indicators = this.$element.find('.carousel-indicators')
    this.options     = options
    this.paused      =
    this.sliding     =
    this.interval    =
    this.$active     =
    this.$items      = null

    this.options.pause == 'hover' && this.$element
      .on('mouseenter.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.pause, this))
      .on('mouseleave.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.cycle, this))
  }

  Carousel.VERSION  = '3.2.0'

  Carousel.DEFAULTS = {
    interval: 5000,
    pause: 'hover',
    wrap: true
  }

  Carousel.prototype.keydown = function (e) {
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37: this.prev(); break
      case 39: this.next(); break
      default: return
    }

    e.preventDefault()
  }

  Carousel.prototype.cycle = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = false)

    this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)

    this.options.interval
      && !this.paused
      && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval))

    return this
  }

  Carousel.prototype.getItemIndex = function (item) {
    this.$items = item.parent().children('.item')
    return this.$items.index(item || this.$active)
  }

  Carousel.prototype.to = function (pos) {
    var that        = this
    var activeIndex = this.getItemIndex(this.$active = this.$element.find('.item.active'))

    if (pos > (this.$items.length - 1) || pos < 0) return

    if (this.sliding)       return this.$element.one('slid.bs.carousel', function () {that.to(pos)}) // yes, "slid"
    if (activeIndex == pos) return this.pause().cycle()

    return this.slide(pos > activeIndex ? 'next' : 'prev', $(this.$items[pos]))
  }

  Carousel.prototype.pause = function (e) {
    e || (this.paused = true)

    if (this.$element.find('.next, .prev').length && $.support.transition) {
      this.$element.trigger($.support.transition.end)
      this.cycle(true)
    }

    this.interval = clearInterval(this.interval)

    return this
  }

  Carousel.prototype.next = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return
    return this.slide('next')
  }

  Carousel.prototype.prev = function () {
    if (this.sliding) return
    return this.slide('prev')
  }

  Carousel.prototype.slide = function (type, next) {
    var $active   = this.$element.find('.item.active')
    var $next     = next || $active[type]()
    var isCycling = this.interval
    var direction = type == 'next' ? 'left' : 'right'
    var fallback  = type == 'next' ? 'first' : 'last'
    var that      = this

    if (!$next.length) {
      if (!this.options.wrap) return
      $next = this.$element.find('.item')[fallback]()
    }

    if ($next.hasClass('active')) return (this.sliding = false)

    var relatedTarget = $next[0]
    var slideEvent = $.Event('slide.bs.carousel', {
      relatedTarget: relatedTarget,
      direction: direction
    å})
    this.$element.trigger(slideEvent)
    if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    this.sliding = true

    isCycling && this.pause()

    if (this.$indicators.length) {
      this.$indicators.find('.active').removeClass('active')
      var $nextIndicator = $(this.$indicators.children()[this.getItemIndex($next)])
      $nextIndicator && $nextIndicator.addClass('active')
    }

    var slidEvent = $.Event('slid.bs.carousel', { relatedTarget: relatedTarget, direction: direction }) // yes, "slid"
    if ($.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('slide')) {
      $next.addClass(type)
      $next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
      $active.addClass(direction)
      $next.addClass(direction)
      $active
        .one('bsTransitionEnd', function () {
          $next.removeClass([type, direction].join(' ')).addClass('active')
          $active.removeClass(['active', direction].join(' '))
          that.sliding = false
          setTimeout(function () {that.$element.trigger(slidEvent)}, 0)
        })
        .emulateTransitionEnd($active.css('transition-duration').slice(0, -1) * 1000)
    } else {
      $active.removeClass('active')
      $next.addClass('active')
      this.sliding = false
      this.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
    }

    isCycling && this.cycle()

    return this
  }


  // CAROUSEL PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.carousel')
      var options = $.extend({}, Carousel.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
      var action  = typeof option == 'string' ? option : options.slide

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.carousel', (data = new Carousel(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'number') data.to(option)
      else if (action) data[action]()
      else if (options.interval) data.pause().cycle()
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.carousel

  $.fn.carousel             = Plugin
  $.fn.carousel.Constructor = Carousel


  // CAROUSEL NO CONFLICT
  // ====================

  $.fn.carousel.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.carousel = old
    return this
  }


  // CAROUSEL DATA-API
  // =================

  $(document).on('click.bs.carousel.data-api', '[data-slide], [data-slide-to]', function (e) {
    var href
    var $this   = $(this)
    var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')) // strip for ie7
    if (!$target.hasClass('carousel')) return
    var options = $.extend({}, $target.data(), $this.data())
    var slideIndex = $this.attr('data-slide-to')
    if (slideIndex) options.interval = false

    Plugin.call($target, options)

    if (slideIndex) {$target.data('bs.carousel').to(slideIndex)}

    e.preventDefault()
  })

  $(window).on('load', function () {
    $('[data-ride="carousel"]').each(function () {
      var $carousel = $(this)
      Plugin.call($carousel, $carousel.data())
    })
  })

}(jQuery);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why haven't you at least upgraded to v2.3.2?

Answer (score 2):

The method causing the issue for you is `.emulateTransitionEnd()` which belongs to bootstrap. You will need to include the bootstrap `transition.js` plugin before loading `carousel.js`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I should have mentioned that the transition plugin is being loaded before the carousel plugin already.